# Twig, comparing variable to a string

Tags: php, string, twig

I have a problem with a very simple template in twig when I need to compare a variable to a string.

The template

```
{% if test_var != "" %}
  Test 42
{% endif %}
```

The PHP code

```
require_once REP_GLOBAL."/vendor/autoload.php";
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(REP_GLOBAL."/ressources/twig/emails"));
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('maj_coord_perso.html');
$msg = $template->render(array('test_var' => "TEST"));
echo $msg;
```

The error

```
PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unexpected character "\\" 
in "maj_coord_perso.html" at line 1' in ***/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Lexer.php:282\n
Stack trace:\n
#0 ***/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Lexer.php(203): Twig_Lexer->lexExpression()\n
#1 ***/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Lexer.php(109): Twig_Lexer->lexBlock()\n
#2 ***/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(469): Twig_Lexer->tokenize('{% if address.w...', 'maj_coord_perso...')\n
#3 ***/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(559): Twig_Environment->tokenize('{% if address.w...', 'maj_coord_perso...')\n
#4 ***/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(331): Twig_Environment->compileSource('{% if address.w...', 'maj_coord_perso...')\n
```

The encoding of the template file is ISO-8859-1 but I'm having the same error with a UTF-8 encoded template.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution :

```
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
```